# How to create moving text from right to left using react-spring?

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

Moving text animation using react-spring?

I am developing a website using reactjs as front end, In header i want to move some text from right to left automatically,but i want to animate that with only react-spring! can anyone solve my problem?

Since i am new to react-spring,i can't find correct solution for this one!

Comment: You mean you want to create a scrolling text?

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs  Yes! i want a scrolling text (right to left) in my header which should start moving when the page renders and should moves continuously without stopping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React-spring is physic based and this type of animation is not really its strength. I would do something like this.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

const TextScroller = ({ text }) => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(1);

  const scrolling = useSpring({
    from: { transform: "translate(60%,0)" },
    to: { transform: "translate(-60%,0)" },
    config: { duration: 2000 },
    reset: true,
    //reverse: key % 2 == 0,
    onRest: () => {
      setKey(key + 1);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div key={key}>
      <animated.div style={scrolling}>{text}</animated.div>);
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextScroller;
```

It has room for improvement. Text length is not handled. Scrollbar can be disabled. But I leave something to you. :)

working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-text-scroller-with-react-spring-siszy

Comment: thanks a lot bro...that works great! thanks for your spending your precious time.

Comment: how to start immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You first have to install the `react-spring` into your project.

For the example, you may include your code into App.js file like as below:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring'

const pages = [
  ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightpink' }}>A</animated.div>,
  ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightblue' }}>B</animated.div>,
  ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightgreen' }}>C</animated.div>,
]

export default function App() {
  const [index, set] = useState(0)
  const onClick = useCallback(() => set(state => (state + 1) % 3), [])
  const transitions = useTransition(index, p => p, {
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(100%,0,0)' },
    enter: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate3d(0%,0,0)' },
    leave: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(-50%,0,0)' },
  })
  return (
    <div className="simple-trans-main" onClick={onClick}>
      {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => {
        const Page = pages[item]
        return <Page key={key} style={props} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I hope this work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mam! actually it work's only onClick, i want to make text scrolling in my header(right to left) without stopping.

Comment: Once the page is rendered it should start moving from right to left!